# Snowflake Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

New to regular expressions in snowflake please help. I am trying to create a column that isn't a 0 or whitespace.

In my example here I want to see 0 as parsed_string for 1st and 2nd records and 1 for 3rd record.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mytable  
( mystring varchar(10) );

INSERT INTO mytable values ('00000');
INSERT INTO mytable values ('  ');
INSERT INTO mytable values ('1234');

select mystring, 
      0 as parsed_string -- need to be changed to get 0 or 1 
from mytable
```

Thanks
Pavan.

Comment: Snowflake understands `rlike` that returns TRUE/FALSE based on whether the pattern is matched. You might be able to combine that with `IFF` (if/then/else) to create that new column.

Comment: The Regex pattern might be as simple as `[^0 ]` (meaning *not* zero, or whitespace)

Comment: One way is REGEXP_substr(regexp_replace(mystring ,'^\\s*$','0'),'.{1}') .. you replace spaces with 0 by regexp_replace(mystring ,'^\\s*$','0') , '^\\s*$' is for any length spaces. Then you substring only the first char/number with .{1} . Dot is represents any character and {1} is only repetition.

Comment: Thank you for the response.This is close but it didn't work when there is a 0 in the first digit of a number. for example '01234' should yield 1 but not 0.

Answer (score 0):

The following examples use a combination of functions to get you a 0 or 1 based on the first non-space character in your string.

I hope this helps...Rich

```
select regexp_count(substr(ltrim(trim('00000'), '0'), 1, 1),'[^0 ]', 1);  --0
select regexp_count(substr(ltrim(trim('    '), '0'), 1, 1),'[^0 ]', 1);   --0
select regexp_count(substr(ltrim(trim('1345'), '0'), 1, 1),'[^0 ]', 1);   --1
select regexp_count(substr(ltrim(trim('  9999'), '0'), 1, 1),'[^0 ]', 1); --1
select regexp_count(substr(ltrim(trim('01233'), '0'), 1, 1),'[^0 ]', 1);  --1
select regexp_count(substr(ltrim(trim(' abc'), '0'), 1, 1),'[^0 ]', 1);   --1
select regexp_count(substr(ltrim(trim('abc .  '), '0'), 1, 1),'[^0 ]', 1);--1
```